# Can the same domain concept be a value object in one context and an agregate root in another?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I am learning Domain Driven Design currently and I'm trying to use it on an application that has a complex domain.

The application is fully configurable, meaning that most the domain objects can have most of their proprieties modified by an admin doing configuration work. Although it should happen rarely and mostly when we deploy the application to a client.

The domain is wine making, so we need different configurations for different clients doing different types of wines. And even with the same wine, different wine maker work differently, which is why most of the domain objects are configurable.

Now to my problem, I'll take one example : grape variety.

Grapes come in different variety (Chardonnay, Pinot Noir for instance). Each grape variety has some properties :

- A name
- The color of the grape
- The volume of juice produced for a weight of grapes

Now, the way I see it, we have 3 main contexts in the application :

- The **vineyard context**, where the grape variety is used as a **value object** for a plot of land. (Meaning on this plot of land, the grape vines are Chardonnay) and only the name is needed.
- The **winery context**, where the grape variety is used as a **value object** associated to tanks containing wine in the making. In this context the volume of juice produced is needed.
- The **configuration context**, where the grape variety is an **agregate root** and we can edit its proprieties.

So now my questions :

- Is the wine variety really a value object in my first two contexts ? Or is it simply en entity ? In those contexts, the object can't be modified, its attributes are what matters but the app should only allow the wine variety that are in the database.
- Can the same concept be an entity (or value object) in one context and an agregate root in another ?
- Should I really make a "configuration" context ? How could I handle the fact that there is the business side of the app and the configuration side ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea that you seem to be missing is "reference data".  That's not a DDD concept particularly (it's not something you missed reading the Eric Evans book).  [Pat Helland](http://cidrdb.org/cidr2005/papers/P12.pdf) offers this definition

> Reference data refers to a type of information that is created and/or managed by a single service and published to other services for their use

From what you describe, there is some concept like a "catalog of grape varieties"; vineyards, wineries, and distilleries might be sharing copies of a catalog, and in particular sharing a common set of identifiers of varieties.

The business intelligence that determines what entries belong in the catalog, might reasonably live somewhere else.  So we might have a domain model responsible for navigating the processes of creating the next version of the catalog, and publishing new editions that can be used in the other contexts.

That said, if those processes are simple data update operations (create/update/delete) -- that sounds more like you have a *database* than you do a *service*.

> A service that has only data is a database, not a service -- [Udi Dahan](https://vimeo.com/113515335)

In the Cargo Shipping example, [Locations](https://github.com/citerus/dddsample-core/blob/master/src/main/java/se/citerus/dddsample/domain/model/location/Location.java) are implemented as "entities".  One of the important values in the Location model is something called Unlocode.

What [Unlocode](https://unece.org/trade/cefact/unlocode-code-list-country-and-territory) actually is: a standardized identifier published by the United Nations Centre for Trade Facilitation and Electronic Business.  There are business processes "over there" that serve to maintain and publish the list of codes, but in the cargo shipping app, you just "import" the information you need.